# error when trying to generate g.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I am making a project and I decided to use hive as my local storage so I added the package to the `pubspec.yaml` file as you can see below:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  # hive database
  hive: ^2.0.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0

  # format dates
  intl: ^0.17.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # hive database generators
  build_runner: ^1.12.2
  hive_generator: ^1.0.1
```

[image]

then I created a class to store the data in
as you can see below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part "switch.g.dart";

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Switch extends HiveObject{

  @HiveField(0)
  late String name;

  @HiveField(1)
  late int age;

  @HiveField(2)
  late String country;

  Switch(this.name,this.age,this.country);

}
```

[image]

the problem is it keep giving me error at "switch.g.dart"
I tried several commands to generate swith.g.dart file
like : flutter packages pub run build_runner build
flutter pub run build_runner build

[image]

but it want generate the file so what should i do is there any other way to generate it
Thank you.

Comment: try naming the class different, switch is a reserved word, maybe its conflicting when generating the file

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the [comment by @EdwynZN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68431299/error-when-trying-to-generate-g-dart-file/69832901#comment120938994_68431299),

> try naming the class different, switch is a reserved word, maybe its conflicting when generating the file

executing the command `flutter clean` and after that `flutter pub get` should help the IDE to start reindexing and find the generated file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).